# Relocation R_X86_64_32S against '_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: python, dlib

I'm trying to install the `dlib` Python library. On some systems (macOS, stock Ubuntu 14.04) `pip install dlib` works fine, but in the Ubuntu 14.x that's part of our CircleCI environment it fails with the following error.

```
Linking CXX shared library dlib.so
   /usr/bin/ld: /opt/circleci/python/2.7.11/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against '_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
   error: cmake build failed!
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: I had a related issue for Ubuntu 18.04 out of the box with Python3 and I opened a question at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169364/building-python-3-c-extension-modules-in-ubuntu-18-04-fails-with-relocation-r-x

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem was that Python needs to be compiled with the `--enable-shared` flag for the `dlib` install to succeed. While in some cases the system Python is built with this flag (e.g. on Ubuntu), the one we were using in the CI environment was installed via `pyenv` which doesn't set it by default.

The solution was to reinstall the `pyenv`-provided Python with the flag set like this:

`PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install --force 2.7.11`

To ensure this gets used:

`machine:
  python:
    version: 2.7.11 # Has to match the pyenv-installed version`

Answer (score 2):

As an FYI, my particular case was resolved by renaming '/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a' to '/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a.moved'. According to 'yum whatprovides /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a' output, this was not installed as a part of any packages installed via yum. Moving this out of the way in this case, solved my issue.

Here was my original error message:

```
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Given that none of my installed packages accounted for the .a lib, moving it aside was an option for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem when building `matplotlib` (a dependency for `scikit-image`) for aws lambda python 3.6 inside amazon docker container [amazon-linux-python-3.6](https://hub.docker.com/r/dacut/amazon-linux-python-3.6/).

In short `matplotlib` was giving the same error as OP had for `/usr/lib/libpython3.6m.a`. Turned out there were two such libraries in the amazon docker container:

```
find / -name "libpython3.6m.a"
/usr/lib/libpython3.6m.a
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.a
```

So I just renamed  `/usr/lib/libpython3.6m.a` to something else so that `matplotlib` does not use it, and chooses the second option:

`enter code here`mv /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.a /usr/lib/libpython3.6m.a.moved

After this change, `scikit-image` were successful using `pip3 install --no-binary scikit-image scikit-image`.