# ReadTheDocs Sphinx Build Failing but working locally

Tags: python, build, theano, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

as the title says, building the docs for my package works locally fine but not on the server.
I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 295, in main
    opts.warningiserror, opts.tags, opts.verbosity, opts.jobs)   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 163, in __init__
    confoverrides or {}, self.tags)   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 134, in __init__
    execfile_(filename, config)   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 129, in execfile_
    exec_(code, _globals)   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 709, in exec_
    exec("""exec _code_ in _globs_, _locs_""")   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "conf.py", line 23, in <module>
    import secomo   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/checkouts/latest/secomo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .convRBM import CRBM   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/checkouts/latest/secomo/convRBM.py", line 2, in <module>
    import theano   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from theano.compile.mode import *   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/compile/mode.py", line 11, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/vm.py", line 673, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in <module>
    preargs=args)   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 2353, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. '))) Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): /usr/bin/ld: /home/docs/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC. /home/docs/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. 

Exception occurred:   File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/crbm/envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.10.0b3-py2.7.egg/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 2353, in compile_str
    (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. '))) Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): /usr/bin/ld: /home/docs/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC. /home/docs/.pyenv/versions/2.7.13/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status. The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-I1fypA.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers. Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time. A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!

You can find the C code in this temporary file: /tmp/theano_compilation_error_JSxqVj
```

It looks as if some flag for the python build in pyenv is responsible for the error as far as I understood it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42582712/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-py-notimplementedstruct-can-not-be-used-when) post.

This is supported by the fact that the Lasagne build seems to also be [failing](https://readthedocs.org/projects/lasagne/builds/5773840/) for the same reason.

However, what can I possibly do about it? Is it really a bug in Theano or has it to do with the setup of readthedocs.org and that they don't compile python with the `--enable-shared` flag?

Thanks!

Roman

Comment: I searched the GitHub repo and found what [appears to be a related issue](https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/2516#issuecomment-285231367). Maybe that will help you out?

Comment: I read the issue but we are actually not relying on tensorflow at all (even though Theano is doing the same thing, basically and TF has replaced it).
And I thought that Theano actually works fine with RTD.

Btw. Why the downvote of my question? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, folks.

I'm sorry but it appears to have been an issue of RTD. The build on their system started working two hours after I posted this question.
Sorry for that, I really wasn't sure if the error was on my side or if it was RTDs fault.

Best,

Roman